# Assign different color to each bar in a google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to assign different colors to each bar in a columnchart, but when I try every bar gets the same color.

Code:

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Something');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Numbers');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', 40],
    ['B', 17],
    ['C', 7]
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'Megafon 27/10 2011',
                 'width':1300,
                 'height':600,
         'colors' : ['red', 'blue', 'green']
        };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I know this is probably really easy, but right now I can't see it. Please help me.

Thank you

Lars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
...
// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

var raw_data = [
    ['A', 40],
    ['B', 17],
    ['C', 7]
];

data.addColumn('string', 'Columns');
for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
    data.addColumn('number', raw_data[i][0]);
}
data.addRows(1);
data.setValue(0, 0, 'row');
for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {    
    data.setValue(0, i+1, raw_data[i][1]);
}

// Set chart options
...
```

=== UPDATE ===

A simplified version:

```
...
// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

var raw_data = {
    'A':   40
    , 'B': 17
    , 'C':  7
};

data.addRows(1);
var i = 0;
for (var index in raw_data) {
    data.addColumn('number', index);
    data.setValue(0, i++, raw_data[index]);
}

// Set chart options
...
```

Comment: I have added a simplified version.