# How to add the different color for each column in the google bar graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

First phase: I've bound the data source

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();

    try
    {

            string sqlString = "select top 5\n" +
            "         b.name, COUNT(codAmount) as ca\n" +
            "        from consignment as c, Branches as b,\n" +
            "        CODConsignmentDetail_New as cn\n" +
            "        where c.destination = b.BranchCode\n" +
            "        and c.consignmentNumber = cn.consignmentNumber\n" +
            "        and c.consignerAccountNo  = '" + Session["AccountNo"].ToString() + "'\n" +
            "        group by b.name\n" +
            "        order by ca desc";

            SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
            SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = SQLCmd;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

Then I've created the bar chart, but it uses only one color for each column which is blue.

I've to tried to append the color by sending the color through array, but it doesn't work.

```
private void BindChart1()
{
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            dt = GetData();

            str.Append(@"<script type=*text/javascript*> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*]});
                       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                       function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Consignment Amount');     

        data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

            string[] colours={ "green","blue","yellow","brown","red"};

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() + "');");
                str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["ca"].ToString() + ") ;");
                //str.Append(" chart.draw(colors:['"+colours[i].ToString()+"'],");
            }

            str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
            str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 550, height: 300, title: 'COD amount amoungst Cities',");
            str.Append("hAxis: {title: 'Cities', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}");
            str.Append("}); }");
            str.Append("</script>");
            lt.Text = str.ToString().Replace('*', '"');
            lt.Visible = true;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

I've also tried to add the color function below like this

```
  str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 550, height: 300, title: 'COD amount amongst Cities',color:['red','blue','yellow','green','black',]");
```

but it only uses the first color for each row for example each will have red color.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938127/assign-different-color-to-each-bar-in-a-google-chart

Answer (score 0):

**1.** the config option is plural `colors` --> `colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black']`

however, this option maps a color to each series in the data

in other words, if you only have one column, you only have one series,
and only one color

to style rows with different colors in the *same* series / column,
use a [Style Column Role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) --> `{role: 'style'}`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Value', {role: 'style'}],
      ['Aug', 3754, 'red'],
      ['Sept', 900, 'blue'],
      ['Oct', 2000, 'yellow'],
      ['Nov', 1700, 'green'],
      ['Dec', 2400, 'black']
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, {legend: 'none'});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**2.** to use the `colors` config option, put data in separate columns,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      ['Month', 3754, 900, 2000, 1700, 2400]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, {
      bar: {
        groupWidth: '90%'
      },
      colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black']
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: u are right that I've only two columns one for x-axis the other for y-axis

Comment: basically I've to change the color of each bar which is coming from the each row of the column, now how is it possible to do so.

Comment: use a `'style'` column, see first snippet above. you can make any row, any color. but you have to add another column for the style. you could also use a DataView, and a function to determine the color. if you don't want to add a column to the data...