# How to use values from an ajax request in google charts?

Tags: ajax, google-visualization

I am creating an array of objects using Ajax to use as values in a google line chart, however the values do not render even though I can view them through the console.

I have tried using ajax complete function to call the charts once the values are set but it still doesn't work, I suspect it's due to scoping but I don't know how to resolve it. here is my code

complete array

```
studentCount[
  { 
    month:1,
    count:5
  },
  { 
    month:2,
    count:3
  },
  { 
    month:3,
    count:9
  },
  { 
    month:4,
    count:0
  }
  { 
    month:5,
    count:4
  }
  etc...
]
```

code

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            studentCount[data[i].month -1].count = data[i].count;
        }   
    }
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(studentCount[0].count)) //returns correct value

    function drawLineColors() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', '2015'],
            ['January', studentCount[0].count],
            ['Febuary', studentCount[1].count],
            ['March', studentCount[2].count],
            ['April', studentCount[3].count],
            ['May', studentCount[4].count],
            ['June', studentCount[5].count],
            ['July', studentCount[6].count],
            ['August', studentCount[7].count],
            ['Septembre', studentCount[8].count],
            ['October', studentCount[9].count],
            ['November', studentCount[10].count],
            ['December', studentCount[11].count]
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Month'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Number of Students'
            },
            colors: ['#4285f4', '#db4437']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend loading `google` first, you can include the `callback` directly in the `load` statement

once loaded, then call ajax

see following working snippet, adjust as needed to get proper data,
and change `error` to `success` as the url isn't reachable from here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var url = 'some url';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: url,
      error: function (data) {  // <-- change 'error' to 'success' to run locally
        //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //studentCount[data[i].month - 1].count = data[i].count;
        //}

        var studentCount = [
          { 
            month:1,
            count:5
          },
          { 
            month:2,
            count:3
          },
          { 
            month:3,
            count:9
          },
          { 
            month:4,
            count:0
          },
          { 
            month:5,
            count:4
          }
        ];

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', '2015'],
            ['January', studentCount[0].count],
            ['Febuary', studentCount[1].count],
            ['March', studentCount[2].count],
            ['April', studentCount[3].count],
            ['May', studentCount[4].count]
            // etc...
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Month'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Number of Students'
            },
            colors: ['#4285f4', '#db4437']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));

      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['line']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**also**, recommend using *core* chart instead of *material*,

several config options simply don't work with material charts

core chart, use package --> `corechart`
and chart --> `google.visualization.LineChart`

you can use config option `theme: 'material'` to get the *core* chart close to the look and feel of a *material* chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var url = 'some url';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: url,
      error: function (data) {  // <-- change 'error' to 'success' to run locally
        //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //studentCount[data[i].month - 1].count = data[i].count;
        //}

        var studentCount = [
          { 
            month:1,
            count:5
          },
          { 
            month:2,
            count:3
          },
          { 
            month:3,
            count:9
          },
          { 
            month:4,
            count:0
          },
          { 
            month:5,
            count:4
          }
        ];

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', '2015'],
            ['January', studentCount[0].count],
            ['Febuary', studentCount[1].count],
            ['March', studentCount[2].count],
            ['April', studentCount[3].count],
            ['May', studentCount[4].count]
            // etc...
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Month'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Number of Students'
            },
            colors: ['#4285f4', '#db4437'],
            theme: 'material'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, i noticed you had more than one `colors` in the `options` -- [see this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39961709/5090771) for using multiple `colors` in the _same_ series...

Comment: not sure how you're building the json, such as using php, but if you build the json in the format google accepts, then you can create the data table directly from the json -- see [this full example of using ajax to get json from php and draw a chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

Comment: Hey I was building the json through php which got the values from a database, your solution didn't work at first but i just stumbled on some text and found out that ajax wasn't the problem, my studentCount[0].count was a string not a number which google didn't accept. So your solution worked once I converted it, and I noticed my original worked too. Thanks for your help