# Java script google pie chart: show an empty pie chart if there is no data to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I currently have some problems with the google pie charts. I have a pie chart which is finally working and showing me the data in the pie chart.

The problem what i have now is that when there is no data to show in the Pie chart then nothing will come up. I would like to show an empty pie chart if there is no data to show.

As an alternative, i also would like to always show an empty pie chart and then let the pie chart load dynamically the data in the pie chart, so i can see it happen.

Hopefully you guys can help me! I really appreciate it.

I currently have the following javascript:
(UPDATED VERSION)

```
    <div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 100%;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var highRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumHighRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumLowRiskCategory1 = 0;
var lowRiskCategory1 = 0;

var xmlURL = "";
var xml;

var firstDraw = true;

// load google first
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // draw "no data" chart
    drawPiechartblank();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function loadData() {
  $j.ajax({
    url: xmlURL,
    dataType: 'xml',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $j('#loader').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      xml = data;
      $j('#loader').hide();
      createPiechartthree();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text) {
      console.log(text);
      drawPiechartblank();
      return;
    }
  });
}

function createPiechartthree(){
  var columns = {};
  var xmlColumns = $j('head', xml);
  xmlColumns.find('headColumn').each(function() {
    var columnName = $j(this).find('columnValue').text();
    var columnID = $j(this).attr('columnid');
    columns[columnName] = (columnID);
  });

  var xmlData = $j('data', xml);

  xmlData.find('item').each(function() {
    $j(this).find('column').each(function() {
      var colID = $j(this).attr("columnid");
      var value = $j(this).find('displayData').text();

      if(colID == columns["Risk category"]){
        if(value === "5. High Risk"){
          highRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "4. Medium High Risk"){
          mediumHighRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "3. Medium Risk"){
          mediumRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "2. Medium Low Risk"){
          mediumLowRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "1. Low Risk"){
          lowRiskCategory1++;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // check for data
  if ((highRiskCategory1 + mediumHighRiskCategory1 + mediumRiskCategory1 + mediumLowRiskCategory1 + lowRiskCategory1) === 0) {
    drawPiechartblank();
  } else {
    drawPiechartthree(highRiskCategory1, mediumHighRiskCategory1, mediumRiskCategory1, mediumLowRiskCategory1, lowRiskCategory1);
  }
}

function drawPiechartthree(highRiskCategory1, mediumHighRiskCategory1, mediumRiskCategory1, mediumLowRiskCategory1, lowRiskCategory1) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    ['Very low', 0],
    ['High Risk', highRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium High Risk', mediumHighRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium Risk', mediumRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium Low Risk', mediumLowRiskCategory1],
    ['Low Risk', lowRiskCategory1],
    ['Very high',  0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      // allow room for selection highlight
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,

      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['#25b578', '#f05023', '#FF944A', '#F6BD53', '#FFE158', '#6FC968', '#8C8886'],
    slices: {
      2: {offset: 0.02},
      3: {offset: 0.02},
      4: {offset: 0.02},
      5: {offset: 0.02},
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
  document.getElementById('Piechartthree_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  var selectHandler = function(e) {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
      var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
      console.log(topping);
      if(topping === 'High Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium High Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium Low Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Low Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
    }
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
}

function drawPiechartblank() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    // blank first column removes legend,
    // use object notation for formatted value (f:)
    ['', {v: 1, f: 'No Data'}]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['transparent'],
    pieSliceBorderColor: '#9e9e9e',
    // show formatted value from the data
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    // default text style is white
    // won't show in center unless change color
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: '#9e9e9e'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('Piechartthree_div')
  );
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // load data on first draw
    if (firstDraw) {
      firstDraw = false;
      loadData();
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="Piechartthree_div" style="width: 100%; height: ; position:relative;"><img alt="" id="" src="./attachment_dw.action?attachmentId=2233" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; display: inline-block;  position:absolute; right:50%; top: 50%;" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to draw a pie chart, google requires at least one row, with a value greater than zero

---

so just hard-code the needed data...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    ['', {v: 1, f: 'No Data'}]
  ]);
```

using a blank string `''` for the row label will prevent the legend from showing
use the formatted value `f:` to display text in the center of the pie chart
which requires the following options...

```
    // show formatted value from the data
    pieSliceText: 'value',

    // default text style is white
    // won't show in center unless change color
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: '#9e9e9e'
    },
```

to make the chart look *empty*, use transparent as the color and add a border...

```
    colors: ['transparent'],
    pieSliceBorderColor: '#9e9e9e',
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawPiechartblank,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawPiechartblank() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    // blank first column removes legend,
    // use object notation for formatted value (f:)
    ['', {v: 1, f: 'No Data'}]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['transparent'],
    pieSliceBorderColor: '#9e9e9e',
    // show formatted value from the data
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    // default text style is white
    // won't show in center unless change color
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: '#9e9e9e'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('Piechartthree_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="Piechartthree_div"></div>
```

---

to start with an *empty* chart, load google first, draw the blank chart

```
// load google first
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // draw "no data" chart
    drawPiechartblank();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

then wait for the `'ready'` event before sending the first request for data...

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    if (firstDraw) {
      firstDraw = false;
      loadData();
    }
  });
```

---

see following snippet, with notes in comments...

```
<div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 100%;">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>

var highRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumHighRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumRiskCategory1 = 0;
var mediumLowRiskCategory1 = 0;
var lowRiskCategory1 = 0;

var xmlURL = "XMLLINK";
var xml;

var firstDraw = true;

// load google first
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // draw "no data" chart
    drawPiechartblank();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function loadData() {
  $j.ajax({
    url: xmlURL,
    dataType: 'xml',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $j('#loader').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      xml = data;
      $j('#loader').hide();
      createPiechartthree();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text) {
      drawPiechartblank();
      return;
    }
  });
}

function createPiechartthree(){
  var columns = {};
  var xmlColumns = $j('head', xml);
  xmlColumns.find('headColumn').each(function() {
    var columnName = $j(this).find('columnValue').text();
    var columnID = $j(this).attr('columnid');
    columns[columnName] = (columnID);
  });

  var xmlData = $j('data', xml);

  xmlData.find('item').each(function() {
    $j(this).find('column').each(function() {
      var colID = $j(this).attr("columnid");
      var value = $j(this).find('displayData').text();

      if(colID == columns["Risk category"]){
        if(value === "5. High Risk"){
          highRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "4. Medium High Risk"){
          mediumHighRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "3. Medium Risk"){
          mediumRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "2. Medium Low Risk"){
          mediumLowRiskCategory1++;
        }
        else if(value === "1. Low Risk"){
          lowRiskCategory1++;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // check for data
  if ((highRiskCategory1 + mediumHighRiskCategory1 + mediumRiskCategory1 + mediumLowRiskCategory1 + lowRiskCategory1) === 0) {
    drawPiechartblank();
  } else {
    drawPiechartthree(highRiskCategory1, mediumHighRiskCategory1, mediumRiskCategory1, mediumLowRiskCategory1, lowRiskCategory1);
  }
}

function drawPiechartthree(highRiskCategory1, mediumHighRiskCategory1, mediumRiskCategory1, mediumLowRiskCategory1, lowRiskCategory1) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    ['Very low', 0],
    ['High Risk', highRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium High Risk', mediumHighRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium Risk', mediumRiskCategory1],
    ['Medium Low Risk', mediumLowRiskCategory1],
    ['Low Risk', lowRiskCategory1],
    ['Very high',  0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      // allow room for selection highlight
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,

      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['#25b578', '#f05023', '#FF944A', '#F6BD53', '#FFE158', '#6FC968', '#8C8886'],
    slices: {
      2: {offset: 0.02},
      3: {offset: 0.02},
      4: {offset: 0.02},
      5: {offset: 0.02},
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
  document.getElementById('Piechartthree_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  var selectHandler = function(e) {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
      var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
      console.log(topping);
      if(topping === 'High Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium High Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Medium Low Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
      else if(topping === 'Low Risk'){
        window.location.href = '';
      }
    }
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
}

function drawPiechartblank() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Is the counterparty a PEP?', 'Amount'],
    // blank first column removes legend,
    // use object notation for formatted value (f:)
    ['', {v: 1, f: 'No Data'}]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['transparent'],
    pieSliceBorderColor: '#9e9e9e',
    // show formatted value from the data
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    // default text style is white
    // won't show in center unless change color
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: '#9e9e9e'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('Piechartthree_div')
  );
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // load data on first draw
    if (firstDraw) {
      firstDraw = false;
      loadData();
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="Piechartthree_div" style="width: 100%; height: ; position:relative;"><img alt="" id="" src="./attachment_dw.action?attachmentId=2233" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; display: inline-block;  position:absolute; right:50%; top: 50%;" /></div>
</div>
```

---

**note**: recommend using the newer library `loader.js` vs. the older `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this only changes the `load` statement...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate your help. I now always get the blank pie chart without loading the data in the pie chart, even if there is data. Please let me know if i have to change something.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I did the following:    error: function(jqXHR, text) {
      drawPiechartblank();
      return;
   console.log(text);
    } But still nothing happening, also no log about an error or something

Comment: Still nothing happening... It's still showing an empty pie chart only

Comment: I updated the questions with the latest code. I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: I am currently using <script type="text/javascript">, Do i have to change it to jquery script type?

Comment: In the updated questions, there you already see the full code and the script src attribute. @WhiteHat

Comment: i must be missing it, i don't see a reference to jquery or whatever is needed to reference --> `$j` -- the only external script source i see in the code is `loader.js` -- when i try to test the code locally, it fails because it can't find --> `$j`

Comment: It's on line 7. the following code: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: no, that's just a tag for the script on the page -- if you want to use jquery to parse the xml, you'll need to include another tag for the jquery source, i'll look for an example...

Comment: take a look at one of the examples in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39961996/5090771) -- it includes jquery version --> `2.1.1/jquery.min.js` -- which makes `$.ajax` available -- but i've never seen `$j.ajax` -- which is why i was wondering which version you were using -- if jquery isn't included, that's probably the problem...

Comment: still not working.. :( I included jquery but still not working, I also tried to change the '$j' everywhere to just '$' but also still not working

Comment: I've done some research $j is used because of the system where we are working in, they are using an old jquery library. So we use $j. So i do not know if there is something wrong in the code now or maybe the code is not working in the old library.

Comment: and there are no messages in the console? if you can share sample of the xml, i can get it working...

Comment: i will get you an sample as soon as possible, probably in an hour or something. I really appreciate your help.